# Bartle exercise 9.N from elements of integration

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

The exercise states:
Let $X$ be a set, $\mathbf{A}$ an algebra of subsets of $X$, and $\mu$ a measure on $\mathbf{A}$. If $B\subset X$ is arbitrary, let
$$\mu'(B)=\inf\{\mu(A):B\subset A\in\mathbf{A}\}$$
and
$$\mu^*(B)=\inf\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(I_n):B\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n,\{I_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbf{A}\}$$
Show that $\mu'(E)=\mu(E)$ for all $E\in \mathbf{A} $ and that $\mu^*(B)\leq \mu'(B)$. Moreover, $\mu^*=\mu'$ in case $X$ is the countable union of sets with finite $\mu$-measure.

My question: I already proved all but the "Moreover, $\mu^*=\mu'$ in case $X$ is the countable union of sets with finite $\mu$-measure". To prove it one must show that in that case
$$\mu^*(B)\geq\mu'(B)$$
for all $B\subset X$. Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: What is $\mu^*?$

Comment: Sorry, it is the outer measure. I added it. @Tom.

Comment: I don't think you need a sigma-finite measure to show the other direction.Since, if $B\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ then $\mu'(B)\le \mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n)\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(I_n)$ now just take infimum.

Comment: But you have an algebra, so you can not assure $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n \in \mathbf{A}$, so the evaluation in your inequality is not necesarily valid. @Tom.

Comment: Oh! Don't worry! In that case we have Caratheodory Extension Theorem

Comment: how do you use it? Because, that only assures me $ \mu^*(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(I_n) $.  @Tom.

Comment: Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433470/showing-that-mub-leq-mub-where-mub-inf-muab-subset-a-in?rq=1) out.

Comment: That one has only the inequality I already know ($\mu^*\leq \mu'$). He couldn't prove the other inequality $(\mu' \leq \mu^* ) $@TeresaLisbon

Comment: @user226755 I see , thanks for the confirmation. Let me see what I can do for you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is **not** the case. Let $X=\mathbb R$, let $\mathbf A$ be the collection of finite unions of sets of the form $(-\infty,b]$, $(a,b]$, or $(a,\infty)$, and let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure. I will show $\mu'(\mathbb Q)=\infty$ but $\mu^*(\mathbb Q)=0$, which provides a counterexample. (A countable collection of finite $\mu$-measure elements of $\mathbf A$ whose union is $X$ is $\{(n,n+1]\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$, for example.)

Let $A\in \mathbf A$ satisfy $\mathbb Q\subset A$. Such $A$ must be of the form $A=\bigcup_{j=1}^n(a_j,b_j]$, where
$$a_1<b_1<a_2<\ldots<b_{n-1}<a_n<b_n$$
($a_n=-\infty$ and $b_n=\infty$ are permitted; in the latter case, $(a_n,b_n]$ is replaced by $(a_n,\infty)$). If $a_1>-\infty$, there exists an integer $N<a_1$, but then $N\in \mathbb Q\setminus A$, a contradiction. Since $a_1=-\infty$, $\mu(A)\ge\mu((-\infty,a_1])=\infty$. Since this is true for all such $A$, we must have $\mu'(\mathbb Q)=\infty$.

Now fix $\varepsilon>0$, let $\{x_n\}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q$, and let $I_n=(x_n-2^{-n}\varepsilon,x_n+2^{-n}\varepsilon]$. Clearly, $I_n\in\mathbf A$ and $\mathbb Q\subset\bigcup_nI_n$. Moreover, $\mu(I_n)=2^{-(n-1)}\varepsilon$, and so
$$\mu^*(\mathbb Q) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(I_n) = 2\varepsilon.$$
It follows that $\mu^*(\mathbb Q)=0$, completing the proof.

Comment: Great! Then might be the equality in $\mathbf{A}^*$? i.e. $\mu^*(E)=\mu'(E)$ for all $E\in \mathbf{A}^*$ where $\mathbf{A}^*$ is the Caratheodory's extension. @Jason

Comment: No, that is not necessarily the case either - in fact, the same counterexample works, since $\mathbb Q$ is Lebesgue measurable. What *is* true is that $\mu^*=\mu''$, where $\mu''$ is defined as $\mu'$ but with the condition $A\in\mathbf A$ replaced by $A\in\mathbf A^*$ (or even $A\in\sigma(\mathbf A)$). Tom's comment on your question provides a proof. You do not seem to need $\sigma$-finiteness in this case.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you.